# What is apptest.java in maven? what's the aim of "test" folder in Maven project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I swear to god. I'm new in Maven. So finally i'm confused in between this file called as `appTest.java`. I created a new project for Maven in Eclipse. But i see three files known as `pom.xml`, `App.java`, `Apptest.java`.

That file is in the folder of `src/test/java`.

What's the aim of `test` folder inside maven project? Can you please tell me?

Now i'm confused about `Apptest.java`.

It contains this source code:

```
package com.faltu.blah;

import junit.framework.Test;
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import junit.framework.TestSuite;

public class AppTest 
    extends TestCase
{
    public AppTest( String testName )
    {
        super( testName );
    }

    public static Test suite()
    {
        return new TestSuite( AppTest.class );
    }

    public void testApp()
    {
        assertTrue( true );
    }
}
```

***Please, Help!!***

***Help, would be appreciated!***

Answer (score 1):

Something like below directory is created

```
my-app
|-- pom.xml
`-- src
    |-- main
    |   `-- java
    |       `-- com
    |           `-- mycompany
    |               `-- app
    |                   `-- App.java
    `-- test
        `-- java
            `-- com
                `-- mycompany
                    `-- app
                        `-- AppTest.java
```

> The src/main/java directory contains the project source code, the
>   src/test/java directory contains the test source, and the pom.xml file
>   is the project's Project Object Model, or POM.

Comment: But ***Question*** is What does Apptest.java do?

Comment: What's the use of `test` folder inside maven project?

Comment: AppTest.class will not be saved in the `my-app.jar`. AppTest is a unit-test source to test that the App class works as expected. AppTest is even in the same package so a non-public method might be accesses. In TDD (Test-Driven-Development) you might develop App in the unit-test AppTest. Really useful, for example to test whether a regular expression does what was intended by doing a test-case.

Comment: @rajaabetaa You can keep your test classes or test cases in thi s particular folder. learn more about maven, very interesting

Comment: @ankur-singhal Can you please help me, what do you mean by `test cases` here? I'm new in Maven.. :( pls.

Answer (score 0):

The test folder is where you put all your test cases, The files under test folder will not be the part of your final distribution.
When you run a `mvn test` command, maven will be using these test cases to make sure every thing is fine.

And every time you run a build, maven is going to first run your test cases to check if all your test cases are passed.

Comment: So i do not need to change or modify anything into `test` folder? right?

Comment: No, You only need to change that if you want to write test cases, If you don't want to write test case, DON'T touch test folder :)

Comment: Can you please help me, what do you mean by `test cases` here? I'm new in Maven.. :( pls..